# Is there a way to have a quadratic behaviour in a CSS length?

Tags: css

I am trying to achieve this:

```css
padding: 2em clamp(1vw, 4em, calc(2.75vw * 2.75vw / 1vw));
```

The idea is that the maximum value of the [clamp function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp()) could quadratically decrease as the view width is reduced. The browser complains that this is illegal. Is there a way to get this done without javascript?